# printout only one time array items

Tags: java, arrays, random, printing

i made this little class that printout in rando my array, but sometimes catch 2 or more times the same index.

es:
2 cook
3 pick
4 relax
3 pick

how can i make it to print only 1 time any item shuffled ?

es: 2-1-3-4 ecc...

i need it to remain an array. thanks for help

here the code:

```
java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();

String[] lista = {"1 drink","2 cook","3 pick","4 relax"};

public String[] getLista() {
    return lista;
}

public void setLista(String[] lista) {
    this.lista = lista;
}


public String randomNumber(String[] lista) {
    int rnd = new Random().nextInt( lista .length);
     return lista[rnd];
```

Comment: random numbers are suppose to act like that, you can remove a number from array once it is generated by `randomNumber` function so that it does not appear again. otherwise that is expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Collections.shuffle`.

```java
String[] lista = {"1 drink","2 cook","3 pick","4 relax"};
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(lista));
// print elements of array in random order
for (String s: lista)
    System.out.println(s);
```